# JQgrid:Get the action from the pager

Tags: forms, button, jqgrid, action, pager

how can i get the action (what button was clicked) when a button is clicked in the pager?(edit, del, add...)

Answer (score 2):

You probably means button of the navigation bar or **navigator** (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator).

You can implement what you want with at least three different ways:

1. You define your custom buttons which look like the original add/edit/del buttons (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_buttons) and use `{add:false, edit: false, del: off}` parameter of `navGrid` to switch off standard buttons.
2. You can use `addfunc`, `editfunc` and `delfunc` if you want replace the default add/edit/del functions.
3. You can use `onclickSubmit` or `afterSubmit` or some another supported events (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) of add/edit/del button to do some additional action on click the buttont or on submit.

You can chose the way which is the best for your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the grid [onPaging](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apager) event:

> This event fires after click on [page
>   button] and before populating the
>   data. Also works when the user enters
>   a new page number in the page input
>   box (and presses [Enter]) and when the
>   number of requested records is changed
>   via the select box. To this event we
>   pass only one parameter pgButton
>   (string) which can be -
>   first,last,prev,next in case of button
>   click, records in case when a number
>   of requested rows is changed and user
>   when the user change the number of the
>   requested page.requested page.

Answer (score 0):

Also there are beforeRequest and LoadComplete events. Examples that worked for me are as follows:

```
beforeRequest: function () {
                        $.blockUI();
                        //alert("before request");
                    },

                    loadComplete: function () {
                        //alert("load complete");

                        $.unblockUI();
                    }
```